# Electron is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

I'm using the boilerplate [react-photonkit/epp](https://github.com/react-photonkit/epp) and everything is well executed on dev when running `yarn start`.

But then, when I want to package my app with `yarn run build-osx`, the app is generated but I have an error when launching it. This error appears only when I try to import **electron**. If not, the app is running in production.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: electron is not defined

Here is my [webpack config](https://github.com/react-photonkit/epp/blob/master/webpack.config.js), the only thing I have added is `target:"electron"`. I also tried with `externals: {electron: "electron"}`.

I tried to import dialog from electron like this:

```
const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;
```

Or

```
const {dialog} = window.require('electron').remote;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to require the dialog modifying the target in the webpack config `target:electron-renderer` which import the module remote.

Then we can import it like this

```
const remote = window.require("electron").remote;
const dialog = remote.require('dialog');
```

And the I can use the dialog from electron. It's a workaround, I didn't figured out why electron was not available but it could be because of the really old version of `electron` and the `electron-packager`. This repo has not been updated for a while and the version were not fixed so it can create issue.

Anyway, for people trying this boilerplate, start with `electron forge` and `electron-compile`!